# One click virtual machine demo?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, demo

I want to give a demo for my customers use virtual machine,  but I don't want the customer to install the virtual machine software, can I make a demo which bundle the virtual machine software and my virtual machine, then just a click to run the virtual machine. It will be cool. is there any tool can do that?

Comment: A VM that doesn't require installation?  That's misleading.  Why lie about how VM's work?

Comment: Well, in theory you could create a VM that emulated an x86 processor isntead of running stuff on the metal ;)

Comment: @S.Lott Who are you accusing of lying or being misleading?  Zhong hasn't said anything about how the VM works.  He is simply asking if it is possible.  If you feel it is not possible, then state your opinion.  I think his question is legitimate.  If it were possible to run a VM without installation, then it might be a great for demoing software since you get a consistent environment every run.

Comment: VMWare Server lets you log into a VM operating on the server itself.  I think that's the version, might be Sphere...

Comment: I am not misleading, I just want know if there is some tool can run my VM without install a software firstly.

Comment: @aaronis: I was not answering.  I was asking why would they mislead. VMWare *requires* installation and configuration (and sometimes tuning).  To demonstrate otherwise is simply not showing how VMware really works.   Why would someone demonstrate software in way that's not how  it really works?  I'm asking why so I can understand the context of the question.

Comment: @S.Lott The impression I got is that he is not demonstrating how VM works.  Instead, he wants to demonstrate something of his own, maybe a software package, and the VM is just a way for him to go to a customer, with a VM setup in advance with a demo of his software already installed.  This would be good for a sales person who can just give someone a $10 thumb drive and the person can run a VM and play with the software installed inside the VM, without actually changing their own system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [Portable VirtualBox](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=926&sid=d066e90532eb0cb0fa10fcc0daa9f426) as per this forum thread. I have not tried it myself but it seems like some people have had luck with it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a virtual machine that doesn't need to be installed. If using Windows, the Microsoft Virtual PC is a relatively compact, free, quick-to-install option for a VM.

One other option would be to install an OS and your demo onto a USB flash drive. As long as the computer used can boot from USB (which is pretty common in newer computers), then you can have complete control over the OS in this fashion.

**EDIT:** Sun VirtualBox is free VM software. You do have to install it, but I've found that it works well, plus it's free.